# How do you uniquely identify a user on Android?

Tags: android, google-play

My app uses licensing and **in-app billing** for **subscriptions**. I was able to use

```
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context); 
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

but that gets a number of accounts. Currently I'm just using the 1st one. I don't know which one was used to purchase/download the app. I myself had up to 3 Google accounts (the GMail one dumb old Google forces you to sign up with to activate your phone, my real Google account, and my work account).

I don't really need the email address, just some way to acknowledge one user is the same even if they are on different devices. If they access the app from different devices, that is ok.

The app accesses a server in the background, so will send the user id to record.

None of the similar questions had an answer, or rather the answer was 'no way'.

Is the most proper solution to have a menu item to let the user chose the account? Or would it be better to save ALL of the user ids on the server and if the user matches one, let them in? Doesn't the license server API provide some kind of unique user hash? (I can't find one, but it's a little fuzzy to me.)

Answer (score 1):

So I'll repeat what others have said: if the only reason you're concerned is to identify the user for licensing purposes, stop right now because the licensing library does not require you to read e-mail addresses in order for it to work. The Play app will be the man in the middle for you.

An app you buy is available to other devices just fine.

The other questions answered 'no way' for a reason.

edit: however, if you're concerned about "unmanaged" products and not just for licensing purposed (you didn't make that clear, only now I'm seeing), then you could pair the information to a given user account. You should use the Account manager and ask the user to select the account he/she thinks is fit. By all means do not arbitrarily select an account for the user. Do as other apps do. The user knows better about his/her own personal information. And please do it securely.

My reasonable opinion.

Comment: Personally, if you're in need of a product that must be available in multiple devices, even after a user reinstalls the app, wouldn't it be more prudent (without you providing more details) to just provide a "managed per user" in-app product?

Comment: Yes. It does. However the server access requires 'authentication' or verification of purchase.

Comment: Did you try implementing the server side check of the in app billing? There is a how to on the Android documentation.

Comment: I'll add an option to let the user choose their account.

Comment: Yes, if you can't or won't use the market infrastructure, even on the server, I believe you could try that. It's clear and transparent for the user. As a sidenote, I'd suggest a privacy policy, sure...